# How can I reply to a comment of a specific person?

Tags: support, comments, comment-replies

Can someone please tell me how I can reply to a comment of a specific person? Ideally in such a way that they come to know that I did.

Comment: Just use @ sign before his / her name if the contact person is not the OP.... if you need the contact OP, just adding a comment is enough like this comment....

Comment: @IamtheMostStupidPerson something like this

Comment: Meta Stack Exchange duplicate: [How do comment @replies work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/43019)

Comment: Now, wouldn't it be useful if we could close dupes at specific meta sites by pointing to meta.stackexchange.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

This you can achieve by *mentioning* (@) that user with his username. For example, to reply to some comment of mine you would write:

> @DarkCygnus so, are you saying that...

On a further note, I have noticed that the @ sometimes "disappears" if you are mentioning the author of the post itself. If you were to mention me on *this* answer the @ will dissappear (as I will get the notification anyways)

Comment: Also important: If the username has some weird characters (i.e. characters you cannot find on your current keyboard layout), you get suggestions if you are able to type at least the first letter of the name. On the mobile app, you can select a comment and select "reply" and it will insert the @ username automatically.

Comment: also it only works if the user was involved in the question: answering/commenting/closing...

Comment: The @ dissapears in the case where only you and question poster has comments, and the question poster is notified. If a third person has commented, then you can @ the question poster